# Grand staff with piano notes using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, musixtex

It is needed to implement a Grand staff with piano notes. I try to reuse a piano code, but tikzpicture plots the piano picture outside the score. the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=0.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \myFrequencyCalculation { m }
  { \fp_to_decimal:n { round(2**((#1-49)/12)*440,3) } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\begin{document}
Grand staff with piano notes:
\vspace*{2.5cm}

\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    %\sepbarrules
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setstaffs2{1}
    \setclef20
    \setclef16
    \smallmusicsize
    \curlybrackets{12}
    \nobarnumbers
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% second fontsize, 4pt possible, too
    \startpiece%
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A A0}\wh{!`A}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B0}\wh{!`B}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C1}\wh{!`C}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B1}\wh{!B}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C2}\wh{!C}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B2}\wh{!I}&\en
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C3}\wh{!J}&\en
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B3}\wh{!b}&\en
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C4}\wh{!c}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B4}\wh{!i}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C5}\wh{!j}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B5}\wh{!p}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C6}\wh{!q}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B6}\wh{!w}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C7}\wh{!x}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B7}\Ioctfinup 1{''s}\wh{!w}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C8}\Toctfin1\wh{!x}\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

 \pgfdeclarelayer{blacknotes}
 \pgfsetlayers{main,blacknotes}
 \tikzset{tight fit/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,scale=0.3]
\def\lastnotenodename{clefs}
\node[text width=1.0cm, tight fit] (clefs) at (0,0) {};
 
 \foreach \note [
     evaluate={
         \n=int(mod(\note-1, 12));
         \midi=int(\note+20);
         \octave=int((\note+8)/12);
         \t=int(floor((\note-1)/12)*7-7);
         \notename={"A","","B","C","","D","","E","F","","G",""}[\n];
         \tonicsolfa={"la","","si","do","","re","","mi","fa","","sol",""}[\n];
         \blacknote={0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1}[\n];
         \frequency={\myFrequencyCalculation{\note}};}
 ] in {1,...,88}{
 
     \ifnum\octave>3
         \tikzset{extract anchor/.style={anchor=south west, at=(\lastnotenodename.south east)}}
     \else
         \tikzset{extract anchor/.style={anchor=north west, at=(\lastnotenodename.north east)}}
     \fi
     \ifnum\blacknote=0
         \edef\notenodename{\notename_\octave}
         \node (\notenodename) [tight fit,text width=1cm, extract anchor/.try]  {};
         \xdef\lastnotenodename{\notenodename}       
         \node [anchor=base] (sol-fa)  at (\notenodename |- 0,-3) {%\tonicsolfa$_\octave$
         };
 
         \draw (\notenodename.south west |- 0,-4) rectangle ++(1, -4);
         \node [rotate=90, font=\footnotesize, anchor=east] 
             at (\notenodename.north |- 0,-4) {%\frequency
             };
         \node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south]  
             at (\notenodename.south |- 0,-8) {%\midi
             };
         \node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south] 
             at (\notenodename.south |- 0,-8.5)  {%\notename$_\octave$
             };
     \else
         \begin{pgfonlayer}{blacknotes}
         \fill ([xshift=-0.25cm]\lastnotenodename.north east |- 0,-4) rectangle ++(0.5, -2.5);
         \node  [rotate=90, text=white, font=\footnotesize, anchor=east]
             at (\lastnotenodename.north east |- 0,-4) {%\frequency
             };
         \end{pgfonlayer}
     \fi
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
 

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Comment: Please add your specific question to your … question. // Drawing: white keys as rectangles, black as filled rectangles or simple lines width large enough line width. After that draw[->] while placing textnodes with Cx.

Comment: I try to reuse a piano code I got from https://tex.stackexchange.com foro, but without success ... You can delete that part of the code as your wish ...

Comment: Please EDIT your question to clarify your trial and obstacles. At the moment it just lists some long code. Clarification shouldn’t be read from comments.

Comment: I edit the question, and also configure: [scale=0.09,transform shape,rounded corners=4pt] inside tikzpicture.

Comment: Adding a bounty won't help get answers to this question. There are at least two if not three (or even more) distinct problems that you seem to be trying to solve. There are both `musixtex` issues and TikZ issues, and the number of people who can solve both at the same time is probably quite limited.  So ask smaller  questions focused on one specific problem that help you *learn* and *understand* the code you're getting from the site, rather than just using the site to give you code you clearly don't understand.

Comment: The musixtex part is done... Just remaining the Tikz part of the piano...

Comment: Your piano does not begin on an A, neither does it end on c5 (here indicated as C8) while your score does. In your score you dit not use the octavation indication. For a musician, "reading" 8 resp 9 helplines is quite unusual. Your eyes do not catch that amount in a glance.

Comment: The piano now begins on an A, and also the 8va symbol has been updated.

Comment: Don't spend the bonus, the answer was not an effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your document specifies the document class `standalone` with the option `tikz`, which results in every picture ending up on a new page. The space you see is the rest of the A4 page that you request with the `geometry` package. The class `standalone` is, as the name says, for standalone pictures.

You seem to need a document that consists of several items. So replace `standalone` by a regular document class like `article`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=0.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \myFrequencyCalculation { m }
  { \fp_to_decimal:n { round(2**((#1-49)/12)*440,3) } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\begin{document}
Grand staff with piano notes:
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    %\sepbarrules
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setstaffs2{1}
    \setclef20
    \setclef16
    \smallmusicsize
    \curlybrackets{12}
    \nobarnumbers
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% second fontsize, 4pt possible, too
    \startpiece%
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A A0}\wh{!`A}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B0}\wh{!`B}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C1}\wh{!`C}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B1}\wh{!B}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C2}\wh{!C}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B2}\wh{!I}&\en
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C3}\wh{!J}&\en
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B3}\wh{!b}&\en
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C4}\wh{!c}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B4}\wh{!i}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C5}\wh{!j}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B5}\wh{!p}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C6}\wh{!q}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B6}\wh{!w}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C7}\wh{!x}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B7}\Ioctfinup 1{''s}\wh{!w}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C8}\Toctfin1\wh{!x}\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

 \pgfdeclarelayer{blacknotes}%
 \pgfsetlayers{main,blacknotes}%
 \tikzset{tight fit/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,scale=0.3]
\def\lastnotenodename{clefs}
\node[text width=1.0cm, tight fit] (clefs) at (0,0) {};
 
 \foreach \note [
     evaluate={
         \n=int(mod(\note-1, 12));
         \midi=int(\note+20);
         \octave=int((\note+8)/12);
         \t=int(floor((\note-1)/12)*7-7);
         \notename={"A","","B","C","","D","","E","F","","G",""}[\n];
         \tonicsolfa={"la","","si","do","","re","","mi","fa","","sol",""}[\n];
         \blacknote={0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1}[\n];
         \frequency={\myFrequencyCalculation{\note}};}
 ] in {1,...,88}{
 
     \ifnum\octave>3
         \tikzset{extract anchor/.style={anchor=south west, at=(\lastnotenodename.south east)}}
     \else
         \tikzset{extract anchor/.style={anchor=north west, at=(\lastnotenodename.north east)}}
     \fi
     \ifnum\blacknote=0
         \edef\notenodename{\notename_\octave}
         \node (\notenodename) [tight fit,text width=1cm, extract anchor/.try]  {};
         \xdef\lastnotenodename{\notenodename}       
         \node [anchor=base] (sol-fa)  at (\notenodename |- 0,-3) {%\tonicsolfa$_\octave$
         };
 
         \draw (\notenodename.south west |- 0,-4) rectangle ++(1, -4);
         \node [rotate=90, font=\footnotesize, anchor=east] 
             at (\notenodename.north |- 0,-4) {%\frequency
             };
         \node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south]  
             at (\notenodename.south |- 0,-8) {%\midi
             };
         \node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south] 
             at (\notenodename.south |- 0,-8.5)  {%\notename$_\octave$
             };
     \else
         \begin{pgfonlayer}{blacknotes}
         \fill ([xshift=-0.25cm]\lastnotenodename.north east |- 0,-4) rectangle ++(0.5, -2.5);
         \node  [rotate=90, text=white, font=\footnotesize, anchor=east]
             at (\lastnotenodename.north east |- 0,-4) {%\frequency
             };
         \end{pgfonlayer}
     \fi
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated code version is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{article}
%\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=0.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \myFrequencyCalculation { m }
  { \fp_to_decimal:n { round(2**((#1-49)/12)*440,3) } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}%0-0-100
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%341-80-70 

\begin{document}
Grand staff with piano notes:
\vspace*{2.5cm}

\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    %\sepbarrules
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setstaffs2{1}
    \setclef20
    \setclef16
    \smallmusicsize
    \curlybrackets{12}
    \nobarnumbers
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% second fontsize, 4pt possible, too
    \startpiece%
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A A0}\wh{!`A}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B0}\wh{!`B}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\color{red-undar}\bf\A C1}\wh{!`C}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B1}\wh{!B}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\color{red-undar}\bf\A C2}\wh{!C}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B2}\wh{!I}&\en
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\color{red-undar}\bf\A C3}\wh{!J}&\en
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B3}\wh{!b}&\en
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\color{red-undar}\bf\A C4}\wh{!c}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B4}\wh{!i}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\color{red-undar}\bf\A C5}\wh{!j}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B5}\wh{!p}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\color{red-undar}\bf\A C6}\wh{!q}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B6}\wh{!w}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\color{red-undar}\bf\A C7}\wh{!x}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B7}\addspace{-0.5em}\def\octnumberup{\ppffsixteen8$^{va}$}\octfinup{21}{1.3}\addspace{0.5em}\wh{!w}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\color{red-undar}\bf\A C8}\wh{!x}\en
    %\notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B7}\Ioctfinup 1{''s}\wh{!w}\en
    %\notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C8}\Toctfin1\wh{!x}\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

 \pgfdeclarelayer{blacknotes}
 \pgfsetlayers{main,blacknotes}
 \tikzset{tight fit/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,scale=0.33]
%\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {
\def\lastnotenodename{clefs}
\node[text width=1.0cm, tight fit] (clefs) at (0,0) {};

 \foreach \note [
     evaluate={
         \n=int(mod(\note-1, 12));
         \midi=int(\note+20);
         \octave=int((\note+8)/12);
         \t=int(floor((\note-1)/12)*7-7);
         \notename={"A","","B","C","","D","","E","F","","G",""}[\n];
         \tonicsolfa={"la","","si","do","","re","","mi","fa","","sol",""}[\n];
         \blacknote={0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1}[\n];
         \frequency={\myFrequencyCalculation{\note}};}
 ] in {1,...,88}{
 
     \ifnum\octave>3
         \tikzset{extract anchor/.style={anchor=south west, at=(\lastnotenodename.south east)}}
     \else
         \tikzset{extract anchor/.style={anchor=north west, at=(\lastnotenodename.north east)}}
     \fi
     \ifnum\blacknote=0
         \edef\notenodename{\notename_\octave}
         \node (\notenodename) [tight fit,text width=1cm, extract anchor/.try]  {};
         \xdef\lastnotenodename{\notenodename}       
         \node [anchor=base] (sol-fa)  at (\notenodename |- 0,-3) {%\tonicsolfa$_\octave$
         };
 
         \draw (\notenodename.south west |- 0,-4) rectangle ++(1, -4);
         \node [rotate=90, font=\footnotesize, anchor=east] 
             at (\notenodename.north |- 0,-4) {%\frequency
             };
         \node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south]  
             at (\notenodename.south |- 0,-8) {%\midi
             };
         \node [font=\footnotesize, anchor=south] 
             at (\notenodename.south |- 0,-8.5)  {%\notename$_\octave$
             };
     \else
         \begin{pgfonlayer}{blacknotes}
         \fill ([xshift=-0.25cm]\lastnotenodename.north east |- 0,-4) rectangle ++(0.5, -2.5);
         \node  [rotate=90, text=white, font=\footnotesize, anchor=east]
             at (\lastnotenodename.north east |- 0,-4) {%\frequency
             };
         \end{pgfonlayer}
     \fi
 }
%};
%\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
\begin{scope}%[x={(clefs.south east)+8.5cm},y={(clefs.north west)}]
%Código para grillas
%\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
%\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (53,-12);
%\foreach \x in {0,10,...,530} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
%\foreach \y in {0,-10,...,-120} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
%Dibujando lineas y texto
\node[] (c1) at (3.0,-10) {\LARGE\color{red-undar}\textbf{C1}};
\draw [-latex, draw = red-undar, line width=1pt] (c1) -- (3.0,-8.1);

\node[] (c2) at (10.0,-10) {\LARGE\color{red-undar}\textbf{C2}};
\draw [-latex, draw = red-undar, line width=1pt] (c2) -- (10.0,-8.1);

\node[] (c3) at (17.0,-10) {\LARGE\color{red-undar}\textbf{C3}};
\draw [-latex, draw = red-undar, line width=1pt] (c3) -- (17.0,-8.1);

\node[] (c4) at (24.0,-10) {\LARGE\color{red-undar}\textbf{C4}};
\draw [-latex, draw = red-undar, line width=1pt] (c4) -- (24.0,-8.1);

\node[] (c5) at (31.0,-10) {\LARGE\color{red-undar}\textbf{C5}};
\draw [-latex, draw = red-undar, line width=1pt] (c5) -- (31.0,-8.1);

\node[] (c6) at (38.0,-10) {\LARGE\color{red-undar}\textbf{C6}};
\draw [-latex, draw = red-undar, line width=1pt] (c6) -- (38.0,-8.1);

\node[] (c7) at (45.0,-10) {\LARGE\color{red-undar}\textbf{C7}};
\draw [-latex, draw = red-undar, line width=1pt] (c7) -- (45.0,-8.1);

\node[] (c8) at (52.0,-10) {\LARGE\color{red-undar}\textbf{C8}};
\draw [-latex, draw = red-undar, line width=1pt] (c8) -- (52.0,-8.1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
 

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: output]

Comment: The document options `[tikz,border=3mm]` have no effect for the `article` class, better remove them. Some site-specific setting is missing: If I run your code with a vanilla installation, the scores do not stretch to the end of the line but are cramped in the left part like in my picture. If you remember which local configuration file controls the output of musictex, it would help others if you could add its contents to your answer, such that your output becomes reproducible.

Comment: @gernot Normally you must musixflx a file beginning with \starpiece to have it stretched.

Comment: @C.Peters Thanks for the info. This is the information the OP should have added from the beginning, for others to help him or to learn from working code.